# How do I extract Mobile Names from following list using PYTHON?

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-science

I extracted data from a website, I ended up with a list including span tag and data I need, I tried some tweaks but cannot find appropriate method. I want to remove the span tag and retrieve only name and info of mobile.

```
[<span class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal">Huawei Mate SE Factory Unlocked 5.93” - 4GB/64GB Octa-core Processor| 16MP + 2MP Dual Camera| GSM Only |Grey (US Warranty)</span>, <span class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal">Huawei Mate SE Factory Unlocked 5.93” - 4GB/64GB Octa-core Processor| 16MP + 2MP Dual Camera| GSM Only |Grey (US Warranty)</span>, <span class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal">Huawei Mate SE Factory Unlocked 5.93” - 4GB/64GB Octa-core Processor| 16MP + 2MP Dual Camera| GSM Only |Grey (US Warranty)</span>, <span class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal">Huawei Honor 8X (64GB + 4GB RAM) 6.5" HD 4G LTE GSM Factory Unlocked Smartphone - International Version No Warranty JSN-L23 (Black)</span>, <span class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal">Huawei Honor 8X (64GB + 4GB RAM) 6.5" HD 4G LTE GSM Factory Unlocked Smartphone - International Version No Warranty JSN-L23 (Black)</span>]
```

I want output as following:

```
[ Huawei Mate SE Factory Unlocked 5.93” - 4GB/64GB Octa-core Processor| 16MP + 2MP Dual Camera| GSM Only |Grey,Huawei Mate SE Factory Unlocked 5.93” - 4GB/64GB Octa-core Processor| 16MP + 2MP Dual Camera| GSM Only |Grey (US Warranty),Huawei Honor 8X (64GB + 4GB RAM) 6.5" HD 4G LTE GSM Factory Unlocked Smartphone - International Version No Warranty JSN-L23 (Black)]
```

Above list only contains few elements from my main list. I will remove multiple entries later.

Comment: Can you show the code you used to extract these? Might be easier to assist if we can see what you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract each item in list and load into BeautifulSoup, select all span tags. If you have an actual list of strings I expect '' to enclose strings. Add to a set to remove duplicates.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

aList = ['<span class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal">Huawei Mate SE Factory Unlocked 5.93” - 4GB/64GB Octa-core Processor| 16MP + 2MP Dual Camera| GSM Only |Grey (US Warranty)</span>, <span class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal">Huawei Mate SE Factory Unlocked 5.93” - 4GB/64GB Octa-core Processor| 16MP + 2MP Dual Camera| GSM Only |Grey (US Warranty)</span>, <span class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal">Huawei Mate SE Factory Unlocked 5.93” - 4GB/64GB Octa-core Processor| 16MP + 2MP Dual Camera| GSM Only |Grey (US Warranty)</span>, <span class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal">Huawei Honor 8X (64GB + 4GB RAM) 6.5" HD 4G LTE GSM Factory Unlocked Smartphone - International Version No Warranty JSN-L23 (Black)</span>, <span class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal">Huawei Honor 8X (64GB + 4GB RAM) 6.5" HD 4G LTE GSM Factory Unlocked Smartphone - International Version No Warranty JSN-L23 (Black)</span>']
for i in aList:
    soup = bs(i, 'lxml')
    text = [item.text for item in soup.select('span')]  #list
    print(text)
    text = ','.join([item.text for item in soup.select('span')]) #comma separated string
    print(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

do you mean something like this?

```
txt = "<span class=\"a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal\">Huawei Mate SE Factory Unlocked 5.93” - 4GB/64GB Octa-core Processor| 16MP + 2MP Dual Camera| GSM Only |Grey (US Warranty)</span>, <span class=\"a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal\">Huawei Mate SE Factory Unlocked 5.93” - 4GB/64GB Octa-core Processor| 16MP + 2MP Dual Camera| GSM Only |Grey (US Warranty)</span>, <span class=\"a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal\">Huawei Mate SE Factory Unlocked 5.93” - 4GB/64GB Octa-core Processor| 16MP + 2MP Dual Camera| GSM Only |Grey (US Warranty)</span>, <span class=\"a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal\">Huawei Honor 8X (64GB + 4GB RAM) 6.5\" HD 4G LTE GSM Factory Unlocked Smartphone - International Version No Warranty JSN-L23 (Black)</span>, <span class=\"a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal\">Huawei Honor 8X (64GB + 4GB RAM) 6.5\" HD 4G LTE GSM Factory Unlocked Smartphone - International Version No Warranty JSN-L23 (Black)</span>"
x = txt.split(", ")
mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(x))
list = []
for val in mylist:
    if ("</span>" in val):
        val = val[:val.rfind("</span>")]
    if ("<span class=\"a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal\">" in val):
        val = val[len("<span class=\"a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal\">"):]

    list.append(val)
```

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience.  I updated the question.

Comment: @ArpitVasava I edit the answer, if it was useful please vote up and accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'Huawei Mate SE Factory Unlocked 5.93” - 4GB/64GB Octa-core Processor| 16MP + 2MP Dual Camera| GSM Only |Grey (US Warranty),Huawei Mate SE Factory Unlocked 5.93” - 4GB/64GB Octa-core Processor| 16MP + 2MP Dual Camera| GSM Only |Grey (US Warranty),Huawei Mate SE Factory Unlocked 5.93” - 4GB/64GB Octa-core Processor| 16MP + 2MP Dual Camera| GSM Only |Grey (US Warranty), Huawei Honor 8X (64GB + 4GB RAM) 6.5" HD 4G LTE GSM Factory Unlocked Smartphone - International Version No Warranty JSN-L23 (Black), Huawei Honor 8X (64GB + 4GB RAM) 6.5" HD 4G LTE GSM Factory Unlocked Smartphone - International Version No Warranty JSN-L23 (Black)'

sp = s.split(",")
gl = []

for sk in sp:   
    gl.append(sk)

from collections import OrderedDict    
res = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(gl))

print (res)
```

(Since your each item is repated after a , I used that as separator. Make sure After ever , there alignment is proper) Hope it helps

Comment: sorry mate, I updated the question, can you look at it again?